# Open doc in "office web apps" on specific page

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, office-web-apps

SP Foundation using office web apps: Is it possible to open a doc file on a specific page?

Comment: Can you please add more detail, explain your scenario and what you want out of it.

Comment: Do you mean displaying the Word document within SP Foundation page as part of the page?

Comment: As a longtime SE user, I don't understand why this question is put on several hours **after** I marked the answer as accepted. And why do people add comments to questions with accepted answers here on sp.se?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a page parameter as &action=embedview&wdStartOn=PageNumber at the end of the url.

Change PageNumber to the page number (ie. 10)